# visual studio 2015 community c++ new project window disappears after clicking OK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I click on new project. Select win32 console application. Click on ok. New project window disappears. 1 second later it is there again, without a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're familiar with project creation and have already done it with a different version of VStudio.

Its possible your wizard templates are corrupted. If you are unable to create any other type of project then it most definitely is.

Run the installer again and attempt a repair.

But if you are not familiar with project creation then just follow the wizard and you should have a project being created.

Comment: Okey, i'll try it, thaank you. If i create a c# project everything works fine. I did not test other languages.

Comment: Repair does not help.

Comment: can you upload screenshots of what you're seeing

Comment: It's to late, i uninstalled and installed it. :) that should help everyone